# (PyQT) Remove just before layout and draw new layout

Tags: python, pyqt

I made three QVboxlayout in main layout, and second QVboxlayout has sub three QHBoxlayout which has checkbox and groupbox.
Second QVboxlayout has layout named checkboxlayout.
[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEOEI.png)

When Make button is clicked, 20 x 3 checkboxes and groupbox will be shown in second QVBoxlayout (=checkboxlayout).
[When MAKE button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPEBn.png)

and, Second Make button is clicked, I want clear boxes and labels but PyQT overwrites on just before layout
[Duplicated index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJTj2.png)
(See that index number appears duplicated : 1 and 2)

Without self.checkboxlayout.takeAt(0) code, then PyQT makes identical checkbox bottom
[Without takeAt code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjmZg.png)

How can I remove first checkboxlayout so I can get clear second checkboxlayout?

```py
def initUI(self):
    self.clickedidx = 0

    self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
    self.pushButton1 = QPushButton(" Make ")
    self.pushButton2 = QPushButton(" I am dumb ")
    self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.onEnter)
    self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.hlayout.addWidget(QLabel('Link:'), alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    self.hlayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    self.hlayout.addWidget(self.pushButton1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    self.vlayout.addLayout(self.hlayout)

    self.checkboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.vlayout.addLayout(self.checkboxlayout)

    self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.hlayout.addWidget(self.pushButton2, alignment=Qt.AlignBottom)
    self.vlayout.addLayout(self.hlayout)

    self.setLayout(self.vlayout)
    self.center()
    self.show()

def onEnter(self):
    self.clickedidx += 1
        
    groupbox = QGroupBox()
    checkbox = []
    hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
    vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
    
    for i in range(1, 21):
        widget = QCheckBox( num2words(i) + " " + str(self.clickedidx) ) 
        vlayout.addWidget(widget)
    groupbox.setLayout(vlayout)
    hlayout.addWidget(groupbox)
        
    groupbox = QGroupBox()
    vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
    for i in range(21, 41):
        widget = QCheckBox( num2words(i) + " " + str(self.clickedidx) ) 
        vlayout.addWidget(widget)
    groupbox.setLayout(vlayout)
    hlayout.addWidget(groupbox)
    
    groupbox = QGroupBox()
    vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
    for i in range(41, 61):
        widget = QCheckBox( num2words(i) + " " + str(self.clickedidx) ) 
        vlayout.addWidget(widget)
    groupbox.setLayout(vlayout)
    hlayout.addWidget(groupbox)
    
    self.checkboxlayout.takeAt(0)
    self.checkboxlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
```

Comment: please create an [example], and you shouldn't edit uic files

Comment: If the number of checkboxes is always the same, what is the point of always deleting and recreating them? Why don't you just update their text and reset their status?

Comment: I will create checkboxes dynamically at the end, and this is just test program. :) I couldn't think further except that deleting all of widgets and layouts, and creating new widgets and layouts. I am testing with changing the number of checkboxes, as you say, and it works well. Thank you for attention :-)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I modified/added below code end of onEnter() method

```
item = self.checkboxlayout.takeAt(0)
self.checkboxlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
    if self.clickedidx > 1 :
        widget = item.widget()
        if widget is not None:
            widget.setParent(None)
        else:
            deleteItemsOfLayout( item.layout() )
```

and added function deleteItemsOfLayout(layout)

```
def deleteItemsOfLayout(layout):
    if layout is not None:
        while layout.count():
            item = layout.takeAt(0)
            widget = item.widget()
            if widget is not None:
                widget.setParent(None)
            else:
                deleteItemsOfLayout(item.layout())
```

The problem was that self.checkboxlayout.takeAt(0) delete old checkboxlayout,
but DOES NOT DELETE old widgets, so result shows duplicated widgets.

Helped from this :
[PyQt How to remove a layout from a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564728/pyqt-how-to-remove-a-layout-from-a-layout)